# use Optional Chaining to check for null or undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using this code

```
data?.response[0]?.Transaction[0]?.UID;
```

here `Transaction` key is not available, i'm getting

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

I was trying to check for null or undefined using `Optional Chaining` rather than checking it with `if`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample blueprint of the object you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) works for array indexes too:

```
data?.response?.[0]?.Transaction?.[0]?.UID
```

For example:

```js
const obj = {
  arr: [1]
};

console.log('exists:', obj?.arr?.[0]);
console.log('does not exist:', obj?.another_arr?.[0]);
```